# Не могу подключиться к БД на удаленном сервере

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

Подключаюсь по URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host-ip:1521:service-name
```

Но соединение не устанавливается, при этом через SSH спокойно захожу в SQL*Plus. Предполагаю, что проблема в файле tnsnames.ora, его конфигурация:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhom$
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

CS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = service-name)
   )
  )

LISTENER_CS =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

Я предполагал, что на месте `HOST` должен быть адрес, но введя его, ничего не поменялось, до сих пор ошибка:

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: К `localhost` очень трудно подключиться, если не сказать точнее - невозможно. Через `ssh` Вы оказываетесь на localhost и подключаетесь. Курите мануалы по настройке оракакла:)  
Просто интересно как нуб оказался с ораклом один-на-один. Оракл - это же дорогое удовольствие и к нему обязательно положено иметь штат работников, которые что-то знают и их можно спросить?

Comment: @Sergey В этом и странность, в Network Configuration прописать ip-шник, но снаружи его не видно. Целевой клиент стартапа - корпорации, это их целевая БД. Junior'у выбирать не приходится).

Comment: Целевую БД никто не будет делать доступной извне, из интернета. Firewall должен пресекать попытки получить доступ извне, никакие настройки оракла не помогут. Если ситуация именно такая, то Вам следует организовать туннель (с помощью того же ssh например).

Comment: @kaylil_01 По всей видимости, вы пытались изменить конфигурацию сервера БД. Никогда не делайте этого, это работа DBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> предполагаю, что проблема в tnsnames.ora файле, его конфигурация

Нет, JDBC Thin driver не использует *Oracle Net*, и tnsnames.ora в том числе.

Прoсто нет удалённого доступа на сервер БД, например через *VPN*.

Но раз есть доступ по SSH, то простейшее решение, пробросить порт *Listener* с сервера БД на локальную машину. Простая тестовая программа:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestConn {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+args[0], "hr", "hr");
            System.out.println ("Connection succeeded.");
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Не сможет подключится на удалённый сервер БД:

```
$ java TestConn db.mycompany.net:1521/service_name
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Но через порт на локальной машине, вполне:

```
$ ssh -N -L1521:db.mycompany.net:1521 iam@db.mycompany.net &

$ java TestConn localhost:1521/service_name
Connection succeeded.
```